# Looping over dependent variable in a mixed model

Tags: r, loops, model

I am trying to loop over multiple variables in a mixed model (using the `rptGaussian` function from the `rptR` package) but I am unable to do it despite several efforts. I am trying the following code. I use the following code without a loop and it works fine:

```
(rptGaussian(Arg ~  (1|class)+(1|kit)+(1|sex),
    grname=c("class","kit","sex","Fixed"),
    data=ggm2, nboot=10, npermut=10, adjusted=FALSE)
```

However, when I try to loop more variables I get the error

> Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute

I am trying the following code for the loop.

```
varlist<-c("var1", "var2")

blups.models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  rptGaussian(substitute(i ~  (1|class)+(1|kit)+(1|sex), 
    list(i = as.name(x))), 
      grname=c("class","kit","lab","Fixed"),
      data=ggm2, nboot=10, npermut=10, adjusted=FALSE)
})
```

Here is a dummy data table:

```
sex class   kit var1    var2    var3    var4
Female  A   Cont    10.79730768 10  20  18
Female  A   Exp 11.2474347  17  1   17
Female  A   Cont    11.64820939 10  5   17
Female  A   Exp 15.62800413 20  8   4
Female  B   Cont    12.41705885 5   16  8
Female  B   Exp 12.80249244 9   10  1
Female  B   Cont    10.76949177 6   13  2
Female  B   Exp 14.71370141 7   12  11
Male    A   Cont    8.931529823 8   3   6
Male    A   Exp 10.46899683 3   12  13
Male    A   Cont    8.363257621 3   13  17
Male    A   Exp 8.753117911 10  16  10
Male    B   Cont    9.110946315 9   13  4
Male    B   Exp 9.595131886 18  10  17
Male    B   Cont    9.454670188 1   10  11
Male    B   Exp 10.59379123 11  1   3
```

Comment: you should tell us that `rptGaussian` is from the `rptR` package.  And tell us what's not working (are you getting error messages? or the wrong answer? or ... ?)  And ideally give us a repeatable example?

Comment: Hi Ben! Thanks I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to paste the data as a table.

Comment: Thank you Ben for the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this kind of looping is easier (IMO) with string-based solutions, especially the `reformulate()` wrapper function, than with `substitute()`.

I used `read.table(header=TRUE,text="...")` to read the data above and this slightly modified code for the single model:

```
library(rptR)
r1 <- rptGaussian(var1 ~  (1|class)+(1|kit)+(1|sex),
    grname=c("class","kit","sex","Fixed"),
    data=ggm2, nboot=10, npermut=10, adjusted=FALSE)
```

For multiple models:

```
varlist <- c("var1", "var2")
```

Make list of formulas:

```
formulas <- lapply(varlist,
          reformulate,
          termlabels="(1|class)+(1|kit)+(1|sex)")
```

Apply `rptGaussian` to formulas:

```
blups.models <- lapply(formulas, 
      rptGaussian,
      grname=c("class","kit","sex","Fixed"),
      data=ggm2, nboot=10, npermut=10, adjusted=FALSE)
```

If you want to collapse the results to a nice form, you have to figure out how to extract the results from a *single* fit into a data frame or similar structure. In this case the result is a `rpt` object and `methods(class="rpt")` tells you that there are only `print`, `plot`, and `summary` methods, but the `summary()` method returns an object that has lots of potentially useful bits. Here's an example:

```
## extract estimates and standard errors of estimates as a 1-row data frame
sumfun <- function(x) {
    ss <- summary(x)
    se.names <- paste(rownames(ss$se),"se",sep=".")
    cbind(ss$R,setNames(as.data.frame(t(ss$se)),se.names))
}
```

A possibly-better alternative would be to return `data.frame(term=names(ss$R),rpt=unlist(ss$R),se=ss$se)` (a 3-column by n-row data frame) instead.

I'm going to use `dplyr::bind_rows()` because it's handy, but you could use base-R tools (`do.call(rbind(...))`) instead if you prefer.

```
names(blups.models) <- varlist
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(blups.models,sumfun),
                 .id="var")

   var class       kit        sex Fixed   class.se    kit.se    sex.se Fixed.se
1 var1     0 0.1444659 0.65887365     0 0.04992624 0.2136589 0.2954982        0
2 var2     0 0.3322780 0.01734343     0 0.01981748 0.2243989 0.1158878        0
```

Are you sure it makes sense to do repeatability scores across sexes and other categories with small numbers of levels?

Comment: Hi Ben! Fantastic. Many thanks for help. You have raised a valid point. The data is not real. It's modified from the beetle dataset of the package (modified to fit the example). My actuall data is much larger. The code works fine. Is there a way to coerce the output into a data.frame or table? When I try to do so, I get error that no method exist for "rpt" object. Thanks again.

Comment: Many thanks. This is what I was looking for. Thanks again.